# How to order SQL data in a custom format and not alphanumerically

Tags: mysql, sql

Please i will like to know if it is possible in SQL to order query results in a different format than the standard alphanumeric ordering of a column.
For example, consider the table "Table",

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzq4s.png)

The following script will order the table alphabetically with respect to Column "Color":

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Color;
```

How can I order it such that Color order is GREEN, BLUE, RED?
That is, how can i order with my defined order format?

Comment: Will there be 3 Colors only ?

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya: No not in the actual project; This is just a sample to convey my intention. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using MySQL:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(Color,'GREEN','BLUE,'RED') ASC
```

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Pay attention to the fact that FIELD(..) will evaluate to 0 if the value of the first argument is not present at all in the subsequent arguments, or when it is NULL. So if any of those cases belong to the possibilities then you need to take extra care or otherwise those will be the top results. In such cases I therefore personally provide the desired order in reverse and use DESC, e.g. in your case:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(Color,'RED','BLUE,'GREEN') DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY CASE Color WHEN 'GREEN' THEN 1 WHEN 'BLUE' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordering by `FIELD` is probably the best immediate answer for your situation in MySQL.  But a possible good long term solution would be to add another table which maintains sorting order based on color, e.g. `TableColor`:

```
Color | Position
GREEN | 1
BLUE  | 2
RED   | 3
```

Then, you would only need to join this table to your current table to be able to use it for ordering:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN TableColor t2
    ON t1.Color = t2.Color
ORDER BY
    t2.Position;
```

The advantage of this approach is that it scales well should you end up having say dozens of different colors.  In that case, a `FIELD` expression, or worse yet, a `CASE` expression, would not scale well and might be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, this will be most useful for practical tables.